# How to Populate a Combobox from Excel or DataSet

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to populate a combo box with a row from Excel. I have tried multiple sites but not finding anything. Here is the code I am using, can anyone assist on this, thank you in advance.

```
    Private Sub LoadExcel()
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
               ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\UserName
\Desktop\Sharepoint_Tables_For_Tool2.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select 'Skill Name' from [Skill DBase$]", MyConnection)

            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "SkillDbase")
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            ComboBox1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Skill Name"

            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to add a column, not a row

Comment: What actually happens when you run that code and how does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: The combobox gets filled with System.Data.DataRowView and the Column in the datagridview has 1 column and it is fill with "Skill Name".

Comment: Your setting the combo box value member to “ID” but that’s not included in your query

Comment: ID and Skill Name are both columns in the table

Comment: Looks like I found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed you Excel Sub to a function returning a `DataTable`. This separates you data access code from you user interface code. Database objects like connections and commands need to be disposed as well as closed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error. Since you are only using a single table a `DataSet` is unnecessary. If you want to use the ID column you must add that to your Select statement. You don't need the extra capabilities of an adapter (Update) so I changed that object to a Command.

Access identifier delimiters are probably [  ].

Set the value and display properties of the combo before setting the data source for better performance.

```
Private Function GetSkillData() As DataTable
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Using MyConnection As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Sharepoint_Tables_For_Tool2.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"),
        MyCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select [ID], [Skill Name] from [Skill DBase$]", MyConnection)
        MyConnection.Open()
        Using reader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return Dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Try
        dt = GetSkillData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Skill Name"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code and the info about the function, I tested and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub LoadExcel()
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim list As New List(Of String)
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
               ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\username\Desktop\Sharepoint_Tables_For_Tool2.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select [ID],[Skill Name] from [Skill DBase$]", MyConnection)

            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "SkillDbase")
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

            Dim Dt As DataTable = DataGridView1.DataSource
            ComboBox1.DataSource = Dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = Dt.Columns(1).Caption
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = Dt.Columns(0).Caption


            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```